# How to Copy a cell as text

Tags: excel

I have a cell (S1) that has a dynamic value in it on 'sheet 1' on 'sheet 2' I would like to take the value of (S1) and copy the state of the (S1) cell - to the second sheet but retaining the value before it was changed.  I would like this to be done dynamically is there a way?

Comment: How is this a programming problem?

Answer (score 0):

With vba you can get the value like the following, just link the macro to a button:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("s2").value = worksheets(1).Range("S1").value
```

Or you can cut and paste special, values only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("S1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

This is a simple way of transferring value of S1 from Sheet1 to S1 of Sheet2.
Im not sure how your Sheet1-S1 value changes but you can put this code in between the transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using vba you need to paste the code to sheet1 ( code section).
When the value in cell S1 of Sheet1 changes then `Worksheet_Change` event will be called and it will copy the new value of the cell (it does not retain the old value). This will be be helpful if you want to create a log of all the values for S1 Sheet1.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("S1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

       ' Sheets("Sheet2").Range("S1") = Target.Value

        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("S" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```